# Other privileges for different communities

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

What is the reason that there are other privileges for each community of Stack Exchange?

For Stack Overflow you can only create tags if you have a reputation of 1,500, but on Database Administrator and Super User it requires a reputation of 300.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the dupe, the reason Stack Overflow requires a much higher rep for creating tags is, as the first and oldest site on the Stack Exchange network, with the most questions to date (**Over 10 Million**), allowing lower rep users to create tags can result in a burden to the site database. Smaller sites, will less questions, and as such, less tags, do not have this problem.

Generally speaking, each tier of site will have a different level of use/questions/users. Private betas, as the smallest user base, needs lower rep to privilege levels in order to allow users to access the moderation tools. A Public beta has more users, so a higher standard needs to be reach for the same quality of moderation. A graduated/Designed site out of beta will have even more, hence the higher rep requirements. It's done to keep disruptive privileges only in the hands of quality users.